# Ruby on Rails compare input with the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We are making a Login system where you must activate your account with an activation code. Every user has a unique code. 
We can't figure out how to make a form that checks that the input of that form is equal to the unique activation code.

The form:

```
<%= form_for :user, :controller => :users, :action => 'check_authentication_token' do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :authentication_token, :value => '' %>
<%= f.submit 'Activeren' %>
<% end %>
```

The controller action

```
def check_authentication_token
  user = User.find_by(authentication_token: params[:user][:authentication_token])
  if user && user.authenticate(user_params[:authentication_token])
    redirect_to @user
  else
    redirect_to competitions_path
  end
end
```

User table

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "password_digest"
  t.string   "remember_token"
  t.boolean  "activated",            default: false
  t.string   "authentication_token"
end
```

Route file

```
Wisemonkeys::Application.routes.draw do
get "users/new"
resources :competitions
resources :users 
get 'pictures/new'
get 'competitions/new'
resources :pictures do
  member do
get 'upvote'
end
end
get '/mypictures' => 'pictures#mypictures'
get '/voteresults' => 'pictures#voteresults'
get '/activatie' => 'users#check_authentication_token'
root 'competitions#index'
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',         via: 'get'
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via: 'delete'
```

Comment: `@user` is undefined. Either change that to `user` or change `user = User.find_by ...` to `@user = User.find_by ...`

Comment: Show your route as well. Is ther any issue with `user_params[:authentication_token]` and `params[:user][:authentication_token]` . Please confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where's `@user` defined ?, do this way instead

```
def check_authentication_token
  user = User.find_by(authentication_token: params[:user][:authentication_token])
  if user.present?
    redirect_to user
  else
    redirect_to competitions_path
  end
end
```